# Creating square iPhone photo

Tags: iphone, objective-c, photo

I would like to require that all photos taken with my iPhone app are square, similar to the way Instagram handles their photos, but without the filters. I can obviously enable editing which would allow users to crop photos to a square but how do I set up my image picker so the user is REQUIRED to create a square photo?

Answer (score 0):

You can't force it to take a square photo.

You would have to trim the `UIImage` yourself as part of your delegate method from the image picker.